# SOLVED - Delete Out of Stock Products Programmatically

Tags: magento2, stock

I'm using Magento 2.2.3 and I need to create a php script to delete all out of stock items from my catalog.

Any idea?

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the script for you.

Create script at the root of Magento

> Root/deleteproducts.php

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);

$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0')
                        //->setPageSize(8) //Set limit
                        ->load();

foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    try {
        echo "Product ".$product->getId()." deleted";
        $product->delete();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'Failed to remove product '.$product->getName() .PHP_EOL;
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n" .PHP_EOL;
    } 
}
```

Now just run this script from root to delete all out of stock products

> http://www.example.com/deleteproducts.php

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick reply. The script  works fine but delete only the first 8 products. Cheers

Comment: @EnricoNryCelone, it is normal to delete only first 8 products, you can change the limit in this line [->setPageSize(8)], add you number instead of (8), or easily remove it

Comment: As @zexperto-WISAMHAKIM said just remove `->setPageSize(8)` limit to delete all out of stock products. Check my updated answer

Comment: Is there a simple way to make this only for simple products? basically a catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id = 'simple'

Comment: @dawhoo Add `type_id` filter in $productcollection `addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);`